# Error on kafka-server console while creating a new topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I am tryig to learn Kafka and just getting started with it.

I am running a kafka cluster with a single broker, and I am getting the below error on the kafka server console when I create a new topic.

```
[2020-03-06 06:26:15,458] ERROR [KafkaApi-0] Error when handling request: clientId=0, correlationId=1, api=LEADER_AND_ISR, version=4, body={controller_id=0,controller_epoch=1,broker_epoch=25,topic_states=[{topic_name=t_one,partition_states=[{partition_index=1,controller_epoch=1,leader=0,leader_epoch=0,isr=[0],zk_version=0,replicas=[0],adding_replicas=[],removing_replicas=[],is_new=true,_tagged_fields={}},{partition_index=0,controller_epoch=1,leader=0,leader_epoch=0,isr=[0],zk_version=0,replicas=[0],adding_replicas=[],removing_replicas=[],is_new=true,_tagged_fields={}},{partition_index=2,controller_epoch=1,leader=0,leader_epoch=0,isr=[0],zk_version=0,replicas=[0],adding_replicas=[],removing_replicas=[],is_new=true,_tagged_fields={}}],_tagged_fields={}}],live_leaders=[{broker_id=0,host_name=127.0.0.1,port=9092,_tagged_fields={}}],_tagged_fields={}} (kafka.server.KafkaApis)

java.io.IOException: Invalid argument

at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map0(Native Method)

at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:924)

at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.<init>(AbstractIndex.scala:127)

at kafka.log.OffsetIndex.<init>(OffsetIndex.scala:54)

at kafka.log.LazyIndex$$anonfun$forOffset$1.apply(LazyIndex.scala:72)

at kafka.log.LazyIndex$$anonfun$forOffset$1.apply(LazyIndex.scala:72)

at kafka.log.LazyIndex$$anonfun$get$1.apply(LazyIndex.scala:59)

at kafka.log.LazyIndex$$anonfun$get$1.apply(LazyIndex.scala:56)

at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:253)

at kafka.log.LazyIndex.get(LazyIndex.scala:55)

at kafka.log.LogSegment.offsetIndex(LogSegment.scala:65)

at kafka.log.LogSegment.readNextOffset(LogSegment.scala:457)

at kafka.log.Log.kafka$log$Log$$recoverLog(Log.scala:809)

at kafka.log.Log$$anonfun$2.apply$mcJ$sp(Log.scala:724)

at kafka.log.Log$$anonfun$2.apply(Log.scala:724)

at kafka.log.Log$$anonfun$2.apply(Log.scala:724)

at kafka.log.Log.retryOnOffsetOverflow(Log.scala:2327)

at kafka.log.Log.loadSegments(Log.scala:723)

at kafka.log.Log.<init>(Log.scala:298)

at kafka.log.Log$.apply(Log.scala:2460)

at kafka.log.LogManager$$anonfun$getOrCreateLog$1.apply(LogManager.scala:759)

at kafka.log.LogManager$$anonfun$getOrCreateLog$1.apply(LogManager.scala:724)

at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)

at kafka.log.LogManager.getOrCreateLog(LogManager.scala:724)

at kafka.cluster.Partition.createLog(Partition.scala:326)

at kafka.cluster.Partition.createLogIfNotExists(Partition.scala:310)

at kafka.cluster.Partition$$anonfun$6.apply(Partition.scala:505)

at kafka.cluster.Partition$$anonfun$6.apply(Partition.scala:496)

at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:253)

at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inWriteLock(CoreUtils.scala:261)

at kafka.cluster.Partition.makeLeader(Partition.scala:496)

at kafka.server.ReplicaManager$$anonfun$makeLeaders$4.apply(ReplicaManager.scala:1369)

at kafka.server.ReplicaManager$$anonfun$makeLeaders$4.apply(ReplicaManager.scala:1367)

at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:130)

at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:130)

at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:236)

at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)

at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:130)

at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.makeLeaders(ReplicaManager.scala:1367)

at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.becomeLeaderOrFollower(ReplicaManager.scala:1256)

at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handleLeaderAndIsrRequest(KafkaApis.scala:217)

at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handle(KafkaApis.scala:130)

at kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandler.run(KafkaRequestHandler.scala:70)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Please note that topic gets created successfully but this error is logged to the kafka server console.
 This is the command I used to create the topic

```
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper 127.0.0.1:2181 --create --topic t_one --partitions 3 --replication-factor 1
WARNING: Due to limitations in metric names, topics with a period ('.') or underscore ('_') could collide. To avoid issues it is best to use either, but not both.
Created topic t_one.
vagrant@vm1:/vagrant$ kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper 127.0.0.1:2181 --topic t_one --describe

Topic: t_one PartitionCount: 3 ReplicationFactor: 1 Configs:

Topic: t_one Partition: 0 Leader: 0 Replicas: 0 Isr: 0

Topic: t_one Partition: 1 Leader: 0 Replicas: 0 Isr: 0

Topic: t_one Partition: 2 Leader: 0 Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
```

Finally when I try to test the console producer I get the below warning and errors

```
vagrant@vm1:/vagrant$ kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 127.0.0.1:9092 --topic t_one

>hi

>[2020-03-06 06:31:06,460] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Got error produce response with correlation id 4 on topic-partition t_one-2, retrying (2 attempts left). Error: NOT_LEADER_FOR_PARTITION (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)

[2020-03-06 06:31:06,460] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Received invalid metadata error in produce request on partition t_one-2 due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderForPartitionException: This server is not the leader for that topic-partition.. Going to request metadata update now (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)

[2020-03-06 06:31:06,577] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Got error produce response with correlation id 6 on topic-partition t_one-2, retrying (1 attempts left). Error: NOT_LEADER_FOR_PARTITION (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)

[2020-03-06 06:31:06,577] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Received invalid metadata error in produce request on partition t_one-2 due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderForPartitionException: This server is not the leader for that topic-partition.. Going to request metadata update now (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)

[2020-03-06 06:31:06,699] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Got error produce response with correlation id 8 on topic-partition t_one-2, retrying (0 attempts left). Error: NOT_LEADER_FOR_PARTITION (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)

[2020-03-06 06:31:06,699] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Received invalid metadata error in produce request on partition t_one-2 due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderForPartitionException: This server is not the leader for that topic-partition.. Going to request metadata update now (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)

[2020-03-06 06:31:06,805] ERROR Error when sending message to topic t_one with key: null, value: 2 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderForPartitionException: This server is not the leader for that topic-partition.

[2020-03-06 06:31:06,820] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Received invalid metadata error in produce request on partition t_one-2 due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderForPartitionException: This server is not the leader for that topic-partition.. Going to request metadata update now (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
```

And if I launch the kafka-console-consumer I don't see any messages which I obvious because producer is throwing the above error.

I think the error I see on kafka-console-producer are result of error generated after creating the topic but being very new to kafka I am not sure what is wrong here and how to fix it.

Comment: Share the command you used to create the topic.!

Comment: Just updated the question

Comment: This error is not generated because of the producer or topic creation command. but seems like there is an issue with your zookeeper and broker configs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not properly configured the kafka. could you please look at your server.properties?? did you specify log directory?

Comment: this is how `log.dirs=s=/vagrant/kafka_2.11-2.4.0/data/kafka` looks like.

Answer (score 0):

There was some issue with the filesystem on which `log.dirs` was hosted, and it took me quite some time to figure out as the topic was being created. I changed the `log.dirs` to some other file system and it worked for me.